# Cannot import json-simple with Maven

Tags: java, json, maven

I am trying to import json-simple with maven using :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>JSONtest</groupId>
<artifactId>JSONtest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried to use the library, but it does not appear to me. (there should be a package called json)

[import picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVzkt.png)

Then I found out that I am getting this error : Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1

I am pretty new to maven, is there something I am missing ?

Comment: I guess problem with repos settings. Could you show your settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jarlocation/json-simple.1.1.1.jar -DgroupId=com.googlecode.json-simple  -DartifactId=json-simple -Dversion=1.1.1 -Dpackaging=jar

Run this command in Command Prompt(cmd), then it will be available in you local maven repository.

Comment: I guess problem with repos settings. if it so this will not fix the problem, because maven would not be able to connect to repo

Comment: It says that 'maven' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/install.html follow these steps.Make sure java is installed.

Comment: And also I found out that I do have something in my local repository at C:\Users\myname\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\json-simple, but I don't know how to import it in IntellIJ

Comment: You just need to add it in you pom.xml, clean & compile the project again.